# Simple capitalization of first letter of each word in C

Tags: c, capitalization

I want to capitalize first letter of each word of an entered string.

This is what I've done (doesn't work yet)

```
void main() {
     char sentence[100];
     int i;

     printf("Enter your name and surnames: ");
     gets(sentence);

     for(i = 0; i<strlen(sentence); i++){
        if(sentence[i] == ' '){
            printf("%c", toupper(sentence[i]+1)); 
            //I want to advance to next item respect to space and capitalize it
            //But it doesn't work
        } else {
            printf("%c", sentence[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

Input: james cameron

Wished Output: James Cameron

Comment: The use of `gets()` is extremely poor style. It is impossible to use safely and has been removed in the latest version of the C standard.

Comment: Interestingly, the same was asked 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036553/c-function-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-words-in-a-array

Comment: Also: include the relevant header files `#include <stdio.h> #include <string.h> #include <ctype.h>`, if you don't bad stuff might happen

Comment: @MitchWheat - by `inspace()` you meant `isspace()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close.

```
printf("%c", toupper(sentence[i]+1));
```

Should be

```
printf(" %c", toupper(sentence[i+1]));
i++;
```

Though you should probably check for the end of the string (`'\0'`) too.

Comment: output is: James Ccameron

Comment: Did you add the `i++`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strchr`/`strsep` to search for word delimiters and then change the next character.

```
char *q, *p = sentence;
while (p) {
    q = strchr(p, ' ');
    if (!q) break;
    toupper(p[q - p + 1]);
    p = q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An *alternate* approach: (create a function to capitalize)

***1)***  Create an additional buffer of same length to contain modified results
***2)***  Set first char of new string to upper case version of original string
***3)***  Walk through the string searching for space.
***4)***  Set next char of new string to upper case of char in original string

***Code example:***

```
void capitalize(char *str, char *new)
{
    int i=0;

    new[i] = toupper(str[0]);
    i++;//increment after every look
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(isspace(str[i])) 
        {
            new[i] = str[i];
            new[i+1] = toupper(str[i+1]);
            i+=2;//look twice, increment twice
        }
        else
        {
            new[i] = str[i];        
            i++;//increment after every look
        }
    }
}
```