# C source code to change first letters of words from lowercase to uppercase in a string

Tags: c

I have a C source code, but I have a problem with it. I want to convert the first letters of words in a string that I enter from lowercase to uppercase, but it changes all letters to uppercase. Can you help me solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int count, ch, i;
    int str[32];
    printf("Enter a sentence \n");
    for (i = 0; (sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
    {
        ;
    }
    sentence[i] = '\0';
    /*  shows the number of chars accepted in a sentence */
    count = i;
    printf("The given sentence is   : %s", sentence);
    printf("\n Case changed sentence is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ch = islower(sentence[i])? toupper(sentence[i]) : tolower(sentence[i]);
        putchar(ch);
    }
    getch();
}
```

e.g.

Input: welcome to Sharif university

Desired output:  Welcome To Sharif University

Actual output: WELCOME TO SHARIF UNIVERSITY

Comment: That's because you're changing all characters to uppercase: `for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ch = islower(sentence[i])? toupper(sentence[i]) : tolower(sentence[i]);
        putchar(ch);
    }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple capitalization of first letter of each word in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038297/simple-capitalization-of-first-letter-of-each-word-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You must have check if the current char is a space and then only use `toupper` on the character after the space.

Comment: It looks more of a comment than answer.. please post sample code, so it helps!

Comment: @LeBarbu In general case there can be another space after a space or even a tab character.:)

Comment: I'd love to post a comment, but I must have 50 reputation in order to do so. @Vlad-from-moscow yes, sure, but I just answer the question asked, It seems like a school assignment, and I thought that giving all the answers is a bit like helping to cheat

Comment: @LeBarbu  Is not this your comment?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, but I meaned comment on the original post

Answer (score 0):

```
ch = ' ';
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ch = isspace(ch) ? toupper(sentence[i]) : tolower(sentence[i]);
    putchar(ch);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check for characters which have a space preceding them and upper case them. You also need to check for the first character which is a special case as it does not have a space preceding it.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[] = "this is a test string";
    int loop;

    for (loop=-1; loop<(int) strlen(str)-1; loop++)
    {
        // Possible upper case required?
        if (loop < 0 || str[loop]==' ')
            if (str[loop+1] >= 'a' && str[loop+1] <='z')
                str[loop+1] = (str[loop+1] - 'a') + 'A';
    }

    printf ("string is : %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string is : This Is A Test String
```

Comment: I seems that `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: Na. If it was && loop would have to be <0 and therefore would be illegal to access the array. The -1 is for upper casing the first letter

Comment: Oh never mind the other ||. Alright i'll give the down voter. That's a bug my test plan was obviously insufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

int main( void ) 
{
    char sentence[N];
    char *p = sentence; 

    printf( "Enter a sentence: " );

    if ( !fgets( sentence, sizeof( sentence ), stdin ) ) sentence[0] = '\0';

    printf( "\nThe given sentence is   : %s", sentence );

    do
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
        if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p  ) ) *p = toupper( *p );
        while ( *p && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
    } while ( *p );

    printf( "\nCase changed sentence is: %s", sentence );   

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
The given sentence is   : welcome to Sharif university

Case changed sentence is: Welcome To Sharif University
```

If yor compiler does not support function `isblank` then you can substitute it for `isspace`

It seems that a more correct approach will be to use only `isalpha` because in general case after a blank there can be for example a digit or punctuation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

int main( void ) 
{
    char sentence[N];
    char *p = sentence; 

    printf( "Enter a sentence: " );

    if ( !fgets( sentence, sizeof( sentence ), stdin ) ) sentence[0] = '\0';

    printf( "\nThe given sentence is   : %s", sentence );

    do
    {
        while ( *p && !isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
        if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p  ) ) *p = toupper( *p );
        while ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
    } while ( *p );

    printf( "\nCase changed sentence is: %s", sentence );   

    return 0;
}
```

If you do not want to change the original string then the code will look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

int main( void ) 
{
    char sentence[N];
    char *p = sentence; 

    printf( "Enter a sentence: " );

    if ( !fgets( sentence, sizeof( sentence ), stdin ) ) sentence[0] = '\0';

    printf( "\nThe given sentence is   : %s", sentence );

    printf( "\nCase changed sentence is: " );   
    do
    {
        while ( *p && !isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) putchar( *p++ );
        if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p  ) ) putchar( toupper( *p++ ) );
        while ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) putchar( *p++ );
    } while ( *p );


    return 0;
}
```