# uppercase & lowercase using char

Tags: c

I have work in college and I can not use strings or arrays in C,
The program asks the user to enter his name,
The first letter should be uppercase letter and the rest lowercase,
The program continues to the next code only when it is right,
The problem is that the only thing I can use is `char`,
Does anybody have any idea how to do it?

The only libraries that I can use are : `stdio`, `stdlib`, `math`, `time`, and `windows`

```
void nameCheck(){
int flag1 = 0, flag2 = 1, one = 1;
char name = 0;

printf("Please enter you name :\n");


do
{
    flag1 = 0;
    flag2 = 1;
    printf("\n");
    name = 0;
    one = 1;
    while (name != '.')
    {
        name = getche();
        if (name >= 'A' && name <= 'Z' && one == 1){
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        else if (name <= 'a' || name >= 'z'){
            if (name != '.')
                flag2 = 0;
        }
        one = 0;
    }
    if (flag1 == 1 && flag2 == 1)
        break;

    printf("\nIncorrect input please try again :\n");

} while (one == 0);
```

}
it's ends only when you press dot '.' thank you all again for the info.

Comment: Your college assignment is wrong, or you are getting it wrong.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  Hint - in ASCII, the alphabet is contiguous.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27277156/971127

Comment: If no arrays then you are not storing the chars entered, so it's a basic exercise to check the input fits the rules, and repeat the entry if not.

Comment: This might be intended to get familiar with one-character `getchar()` and `putchar()` functions. K&R book (within first "Elementary" chapter) contains cleanest explanation on this, that I could imagine. Note that unless your assignment specifies exact character encoding like ASCII you should stick to `<ctype.h>` functions like `isupper()` etc. Also there is no "windows" header in C.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and there is windows header in C.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski is talking about standard C, which has no such header.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a global variable:

```
bool first = true;
```

to indicate if we are looking at the first letter of the word.

Then the rest is easy:

```
first = true;
do {
    inputChar = getchar();

    if inputChar is ASCII alpha then
        if inputChar is ASCII lowercase
            if first then 
                "print error message"
            else print char
        if inputChar is ASCII uppercase
            if first then
                print char
            else "print error message"
        else "print error message"
    else "print error message"
}
while (inputChar != '.');
```

something like that anyway.