# Replacing one letter with another in C

Tags: c, string

I am fooling around with C for fun. My program prompts a user to enter a word that they would like defined. Then my program uses CURL plus a dictionary API to return the definition. My problem is that the definition isn't formatted properly, so I would like to do that. That leads to my question.

I need to capitalize the first word of the sentence. The definition is in char* format. I am not sure which C string functions to use.

What I have done so far is copy the first character of the definition into its own char variable. Then using toupper() I converted it to upper case. I am not sure how I can replace the lowercase letter in the definition string with my new upper case letter.

Here is some code.

```
char upperCase;

strncpy(&upperCase, r, 1); //copy first char of definition to upperCase (to be converted to uppercase)

printf("%c\n", toupper(upperCase)); //just prints the uppercase letter to make sure it works


printf("%s\n", r); //print the definition
```

r is the string with the definition.

Comment: Why not show the code you've got so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20036880/1067211

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] on how to write a proper question.  You will get a better response that way.

Comment: buf[i] &= ~('A' ^ 'a') if you are using ascii :)

Comment: @DAhrens ... or just `r[0] = toupper(r[0])` to be a bit safer...

Comment: @twalberg True, my answer was tongue in cheek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work directly on the character inside the string:

```
r[0] = toupper(r[0]);
```

You can do this because the expression `r[0]` is of type `char`. Also note that you can use array syntax on pointers. If `r` is a `char*`, you can still treat it as an array and refer to its individual `char` contents with `r[index]`. `r[0]` for the first character in the string, `r[1]` for the second, and so on.

Comment: Your answer may be a little confusing to the newbie.  Perhaps `char str[100]` or something like that is better.  The newbie may start complaining about segmentation faults if he takes your code literally.

Comment: @FiddlingBits The OP now posted some code, so this makes things even simpler :-)